# Automate WebPageTest

Tags: web-testing, traffic, webpagetest, webloadui

I have created a web application that will have to operate under a heavy client load, so I was planning to test it out with automated services, yet I don't seem to be able to find any. In essence, I am looking for a way to imitate real requests from various locations to my server. WebPageTest seems to do the job, but I can only run it once. Is there a way I can automate it to run every so many seconds?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is a WebPageTest API (https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest-docs/blob/master/dev/api.md) which you could use to automate these requests using a CRON job.

There are also off-the-shelf solutions that do this, such as SpeedCurve (paid service).